# PERSIST vs PERSIST_ONLY (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, runtime, persist

I read [**Syntax for Persisting System Variables**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html#persisted-system-variables-syntax) in MySQL documentation about **PERSIST** and **PERSIST_ONLY** as shown below:

- To persist a global system variable to the `mysqld-auto.cnf` option file in the data directory, precede the variable name by the `PERSIST` keyword or the `@@PERSIST.` qualifier:

```sql
SET PERSIST max_connections = 1000;
SET @@PERSIST.max_connections = 1000;
```

- To persist a global system variable to the `mysqld-auto.cnf` file without setting the global variable runtime value, precede the variable name by the `PERSIST_ONLY` keyword or the `@@PERSIST_ONLY.` qualifier:

```sql
SET PERSIST_ONLY back_log = 100;
SET @@PERSIST_ONLY.back_log = 100;
```

It seems like **PERSIST** sets **a global variable runtime value** but **PERSIST_ONLY** doesn't set **a global variable runtime value** but I don't understand what **a global variable runtime value** is, so I don't really understand the difference between **PERSIST** and **PERSIST_ONLY**.

My questions:

1. What is **the global variable runtime value**?
2. What is the difference between **PERSIST** and **PERSIST_ONLY**?

Comment: The "global runtime value" is the value used by the database now.

Comment: The change you make won't take effect until the next time you restart the database.

Answer (score 1):

***To set **a global variable runtime value**, **PERSIST** doesn't need to restart **MySQL** while **PERSIST_ONLY** needs to restart **MySQL**.***

For example, **a global variable runtime value** is **"max_connections"** which is **"151" by default** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.max_connections;
+--------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.max_connections |
+--------------------------+
|                      151 |
+--------------------------+
```

Now, with **PERSIST**, if setting **"500"** to **"max_connections"** as shown below:

```
mysql> SET PERSIST max_connections = 500;
```

Then, **"max_connections"** is now **"500"** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.max_connections;
+--------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.max_connections |
+--------------------------+
|                      500 |
+--------------------------+
```

But with **PERSIST_ONLY**, if setting **"500"** to **"max_connections"** as shown below:

```
mysql> SET PERSIST_ONLY max_connections = 500;
```

Then, **"max_connections"** is still **"151"** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.max_connections;
+--------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.max_connections |
+--------------------------+
|                      151 |
+--------------------------+
```

Then, stop, start and login **MySQL** again:

```
C:\Windows\System32>net stop MySQL80 && net start MySQL80 && mysql -u root -p
```

Then finally, **"max_connections"** is now **"500"** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.max_connections;
+--------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.max_connections |
+--------------------------+
|                      500 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

> what the global variable runtime value is .. what is the difference between PERSIST and PERSIST_ONLY?

There exists a bunch of global option variables which effects the server. They effects the whole server. Changing the variable value changes the server behavior immediately.

Option variables values are loaded from option files during server start. If some option have no according row in the file then hardcoded default value is used.

Option variables are not reloaded when the server works. Changing the setting in the options file does not effect the server until it restarts.

So when you use PERSIST then new value is written into the option file (and it will be applied during the next server start) and is set to current server settings (the server alters its work according this new setting).

When you use PERSIST_ONLY then new value is written into the option file (and it will be applied during the next server start) but it is not set to current server settings (and current server behavior is not changed).